# How to Generating Dynamic <meta> Tags on the Apache Server with react.js

Tags: javascript, apache, reactjs, webpack, react-router-v4

I've created a react.js + router v4 project via [facebookincubator/create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), and I use Apache 2 without backend language to run my project.

I've read this [official doc](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#generating-dynamic-meta-tags-on-the-server):

> Generating Dynamic  Tags on the Server
>
> Since Create React App doesn’t support server rendering, you might be wondering how to make  tags dynamic and reflect the current URL. To solve this, we recommend to add placeholders into the HTML, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="__OG_TITLE__">
    <meta property="og:description" content="__OG_DESCRIPTION__">
```

> Then, on the server, regardless of the backend you use, you can read index.html into memory and replace **OG_TITLE**, **OG_DESCRIPTION**, and any other placeholders with values depending on the current URL. Just make sure to sanitize and escape the interpolated values so that they are safe to embed into HTML!

If I use apache run my project **without** any backend language, is there have any way to Generating Dynamic  Tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use Helmet, it makes easy to manage metas : https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

**Proof of Helmet working with crawlers**

https://medium.com/mixed-marketing-technology/our-solution-to-make-seo-work-for-a-react-js-site-rankwatch-blog-9a311b86fb5f

Comment: First: OP wants dynamic tag, not SEO optimization. Second: this is not true, an article from 2016 https://medium.freecodecamp.org/seo-vs-react-is-it-neccessary-to-render-react-pages-in-the-backend-74ce5015c0c9.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache serving up the React app you could solve this problem by jamming server side include statements into the index.html.